# Android - Set different ImageView to each item in a list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, listadapter

I am trying to set a different ImageView to each row of my list. All of the Images are stored in my assets folder so I stored the path from the assets folder in an xml file. In my code below I am setting the title and description of each row in the list but I dont know how to set a specific imageView.

Below is my code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Bundle getbundle = getArguments();
    KEY_CATEGORY= getbundle.getString("id");

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = getXml("Images.xml"); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_MUSCLE, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_MUSCLE));
        map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
        map.put(KEY_FILE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FILE));
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_MUSCLE, KEY_FILE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost, R.id.tvfilepath });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return v;
}
```

and here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">  
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#dc6800"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
    <!-- Description label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desciption"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>
    <!-- Linear layout for cost and price Cost: Rs.100 -->
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Cost Label -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Cost: " >
    </TextView>
    <!-- Price Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvfilepath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac" 
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Have you try my answer? sure it will help you..

Comment: [try this](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/android-universal-image-loader/). May be you get help.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your own Adapter instead of using the `SimpleAdapter`. Inside your custom Adapter, implement the getView method to set image to you imageView.

Comment: if you could post an example I would give you the biggest virtual hug

Answer (score 1):

Write your own custom adapter as following

```
public class ShowFriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity mActivity;
private List<ManageFriendsDetails> mFriendsDetails;

public ShowFriendsAdapter(Activity mActivity, List<ManageFriendsDetails> mFriendsDetails) {
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
    this.mFriendsDetails = mFriendsDetails;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFriendsDetails.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolderItem mViewHolderItem;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row_show_friend, parent, false);

        mViewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();
        mViewHolderItem.imgFriendImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_friend_image);
        mViewHolderItem.tvFriendName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_friend_name);
        mViewHolderItem.tvFriendEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_friend_email);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolderItem);
    } else {
        mViewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }
    mViewHolderItem.tvFriendName.setText(mFriendsDetails.get(position).getfName());
    mViewHolderItem.tvFriendEmail.setText(mFriendsDetails.get(position).getfEmail());
mViewHolderItem.imgFriendImage.setImageResource(mFriendsDetails.get(position).getfImage());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolderItem {

    private ImageView imgFriendImage;
    private TextView tvFriendName, tvFriendEmail;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer but this may help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text